# Symfony User Logout After Role Change

Tags: php, symfony, security, roles

When changing user roles (in database or via code) user is getting logged out automatically. Is there a way to prevent this behaviour?

Using Symfony 5.1.2

Comment: That cannot be the default behavior. That usually happens if: you keep your session data in `var/cache/<<end>>/sessions` and you invoke `cache:clear`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reload the user programatically using `TokenStorageInterface`, create new `UsernamePasswordToken` (or whichever you are using) and replace the current one with `$tokenStorage->setToken($newToken);`.

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly.