# Dynamically set roles on authentication

Tags: php, symfony

In Symfony, during the authentication, I want to attribute specific role to my user.

If I specify `->setRoles()` in my authenticator, or my "getRoles" function, I come back to the login page, anonymously

Following code in Authenticator doesn't work

```
public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
{
    $token = new CsrfToken('authenticate', $credentials['csrf_token']);
    if (!$this->csrfTokenManager->isTokenValid($token)) {
        throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException();
    }

    $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['customId' => $credentials['customId']]);

    if (!$user) {
        // fail authentication with a custom error
        throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('CustomId could not be found.');
    }
    if($user->getId() == 2) {
        $user->setRoles(['ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN']);
    }
    return $user;
}
```

This code in my Entity doesn't work

```
/**
 * @see UserInterface
 */
public function getRoles(): array
{
    $roles = $this->roles;
    // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
    $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';
    if($this->getId() == 2) {
        $this->setRoles(['ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN']);
    }
    return array_unique($roles);
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63556903/6127393

Comment: it's really a two-part problem: 1. roles are stored in the session, 2. if roles stored in the session don't match the roles returned from the user entity, you're logged out. (both are intentional). You have to jump through some hoops to get it to work, have a look at user impersonation (there's a symfony page on that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the user object it will not match the one in the database. Symfony will recognize this as someone messing with the stored data and log you out for safety.

You can change how the comparison of the user is done by implementing the EquatableInterface:

```php
class User implements EquatableInterface
{
    public function isEqual(UserInterface $user): bool
    {
        // Example for what your comparison could look like
        return $user->getUsername() === $this->getUsername() && $user->getId() === $this->getId();
    }
}
```

You can find this (in a rather small section) in the docs: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_provider.html#comparing-users-manually-with-equatableinterface